# Making an application in Visual Basic to handle Dialogue in Morrowind?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to make a program for a very catered, specific purpose, to aid me in making a large set of quest mods to the videogame *Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind.* I’m attempting to do this through either excel or Visual Basic, and here I’ve provided a little summary of how dialogue works in the game’s normal creation program and then what I want to create outside of it and improve on.

How Morrowind Dialogue works?

For those of you who may be familiar with the game, you’ll remember that the talking to NPC’s will bring up a set of text, and this text is their dialogue. There are different “topics” that if an NPC has dialogue set for, the player can see the topic and click on it, bringing up a new wall of text, and this is generally how dialogue works in the entire game on the player’s end.
In creating a Morrowind Mod, the way dialogue really works in the “Construction Set” (the program used to create and edit the game) is that a database contains every entry of text, and this these entries have conditions set to them which limit which NPCs can say a given entry of dialogue. So for instance, a topic like “latest rumors”, will have lots of entries in it with lots of different NPCs having something to say about it. The topic itself is a condition of sorts with potentially dozens of entries attached to it, and conditions set to specific entries can also be applied. Conditions can include checking to see if the NPC is in a given city, if the in-game time is night or day, if the player is at a certain numbered stage/index of a given quest line and much, much more. This system is what makes all quests possible and the game dynamic.

What I want to create:

I am beginning a rather large mod project that includes many entries of dialogue, many new and old topics, and many quest and quest stages. I could list all the reasons here but essentially my problem is that the Construction Set has many limitations in terms of organization that make it difficult to make a large mod’s dialogue in. I would be better off to design, set the topics for, and edit all of my dialogue entries outside of the Construction Set program and implement them when I’m confident that the writing and quests are finished.

Essentially if this is too complicated I could just write all the quests and dialogue in Microsoft Word, but optimistically I'd like to do something more dynamic and helpful to me, as a writer, and be able to use real variables to store and set Journal/Quest Indexes, filter dialogue by Quest or by NPC, and easily edit dialogue and quests without getting lost in the normal game’s thousands of lines of other dialogue.

*I can't post more than two links here, but I posted on reddit and there I have a gallery showing how the Construction Set works and what I have made in Visual Studio so far:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/4oap6w/making_an_application_in_visual_basic_to_handle/

So, my intention is to make a program in Visual Studio using Visual Basic or Python that leaves me with a program that lets me write, organize, and set the text for dialogue and filter based on conditions.

This likely requires creating a database file for the program in Visual Studio and being able to create variables in runtime, for the program. That is because I want the user of the program to be able to add new dialogue topics, new journal/quests, and all of these things will have conditions with values associated with them.

Any help, advice, and direction is appreciated. I am relearning Visual Studio (I took two courses in it) and I am unfortunately very new to excel and databases in general.

Comment: This question has **utterly no connection to this web site.**  You are looking  for **gamedev.com** where you can ask this sort of question, and get great answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because absolutely no relationship to this site. Ask on gamedev.com

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that a database of some kind would be needed. However, you could approach this several different ways depending upon your comfort level, money, portability requirements, etc...

One way to do it would be to use XML to store your data. It has the advantage of being extremely portable and transformable. Since this is likely a program where only one person would be directly accessing the data at any given time, it might be your best bet.

Another option is to use MS Access if you have office. This gives you a workable, albeit fairly basic, relational database. This would probably be a better choice if you have 2 or 3 people that could possibly be working in it.

A third option would be a full DBMS. MySQL is free and you could install that to your local machine, or to a remote server. Installed to a remote server would give you the option of allowing many people to connect to it and modify data transactionally. However, this would be overkill if it is only a one or two person system.

Circling back around to XML... That will most likely be your best bet. It is simple and integrates perfectly with .Net applications. It can be imported/transformed to any data-store later once you are finished (or multiple times as you progress). Interfacing with XML via .Net allows you to work with it like a database within your code, so if you design your data layer properly up front, you could even migrate to a full database later if the project expands drastically. The biggest downside to XML would be that it isn't relational in the way that a regular DBMS is, and it is not inherently transactional. You do not have atomic updates, so if you have several people modifying things at once you could lose data if it is overwritten.

You *could* get around that to an extent by writing a more advanced data layer to interface with the XML files, but if only one person is making changes locally, and then the data file is, say, uploaded to a remote datastore later, the only thing to keep in mind would be coordinating when and who can modify that file. Mostly logistics stuff at that point.

Comment: While the overall tone of the question may have been geared more toward gamedev, the core of it was asking about data storage/structure. I agree, the asker may have better luck on a game dev site, but there is still some wisdom to be gleaned from here, and I do not fault them from asking. If I can provide even a modicum of help, that is ok with me. Even if this gets closed, the next person looking for a similar answer might learn something and then ask further questions on another site.

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer. It appears Microsoft Access is the key to what I was looking for. I'll be looking more into how to use it directly, but it appears the best solution.

Comment: Also, I was able to import dialogue from the Construction Set, which gave me a text file. Then, I was able to send that to Excell which recognized the format that the text was in and correctly put that information back together again in a database - from there I sent it to Access. Very helpful!